# elastic-Search Aggregation [python]

Tags: django, elasticsearch, aggregate, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I indexed the post and community models,

```
post = Index('posts')
post.settings(
    number_of_shards=1,
    number_of_replicas=0
)

@post.doc_type
class PostDocument(DocType):
    community = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'description': fields.TextField(),
        'name': fields.StringField(),
    })
```

I want to search posts and aggregate the communities
(returns communities of the posts in the result)

I may need to use aggregation, I had difficulties while implementing it, the documentation was not clear for me.

```
q = Q("multi_match", query=query, fields=['title', 'content'])
document.query(q)
document.aggs.bucket('per_tag', 'terms', field='community')
```

Comment: You need to aggregate on a leaf field (e.g. `community.id`), not on an object field. Can you try that?

Comment: @Val I try it, it works but not giving me the result I want, could u help plz ?
```
    q = Q("multi_match", query=query, fields=['title', 'content'])
    document.query(q)
    document.aggs.bucket('per_tag', 'terms', field='community__id')
    response = document.execute()
    return response.aggregations.per_tag.buckets
```

Comment: `not giving me the result I want` it's hard to know what you expect if you don't explain it ;-) Please show some sample data and what results you expect, it'll be much easier for everyone

Comment: @Val I want to return a list of `Community` object not only the IDs

Answer (score 1):

I think you need change the aggregation to something similar to:

```
document.aggs.bucket('per_tag', 'terms', field='community__id')
```

Because community is a complex objects, and elasticsearch only can do aggregation with simple fields. (keyword or integer)